# Capybara testing HTML emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, capybara

I'd like to use Capybara to test the HTML emails that my app generates.

I'm currently using the `email_spec` gem, so I already have the body of the email as a string, if that's helpful.

How could I get Capybara to load an email?

Note: My final goal is to use [this fork](https://github.com/ablegray/capybara-webkit) of capybara-webkit to render the HTML email as a image.

Comment: What are you trying to test exactly in your emails that something like `email_spec` or something similar won't do?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you would get capybara to test the email. I know the email_spec has the ability to:

- Follow links
- Verify that the text exists in the email

Certainly the cucumber email_steps.rb that email_spec generates provides various pointers to show you how to achieve the above using just code directly at the email_spec level (i.e. no cucumber).

Straight from the email_steps.rb file:

```
# Commonly used email steps
#
# To add your own steps make a custom_email_steps.rb
# The provided methods are:
#
# last_email_address
# reset_mailer
# open_last_email
# visit_in_email
# unread_emails_for
# mailbox_for
# current_email
# open_email
# read_emails_for
# find_email
#
# General form for email scenarios are:
#   - clear the email queue (done automatically by email_spec)
#   - execute steps that sends an email
#   - check the user received an/no/[0-9] emails
#   - open the email
#   - inspect the email contents
#   - interact with the email (e.g. click links)
#
# The Cucumber steps below are setup in this order.

module EmailHelpers
  def current_email_address
    # Replace with your a way to find your current email. e.g @current_user.email
    # last_email_address will return the last email address used by email spec to find an email.
    # Note that last_email_address will be reset after each Scenario.
    last_email_address || "example@example.com"
  end
end

World(EmailHelpers)

#
# Reset the e-mail queue within a scenario.
# This is done automatically before each scenario.
#

Given /^(?:a clear email queue|no emails have been sent)$/ do
  reset_mailer
end

#
# Check how many emails have been sent/received
#

Then /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive (an|no|\d+) emails?$/ do |address, amount|
  unread_emails_for(address).size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end

Then /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should have (an|no|\d+) emails?$/ do |address, amount|
  mailbox_for(address).size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end

Then /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive (an|no|\d+) emails? with subject "([^"]*?)"$/ do |address, amount, subject|
  unread_emails_for(address).select { |m| m.subject =~ Regexp.new(subject) }.size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end

Then /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive an email with the following body:$/ do |address, expected_body|
  open_email(address, :with_text => expected_body)
end

#
# Accessing emails
#

# Opens the most recently received email
When /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") opens? the email$/ do |address|
  open_email(address)
end

When /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") opens? the email with subject "([^"]*?)"$/ do |address, subject|
  open_email(address, :with_subject => subject)
end

When /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") opens? the email with text "([^"]*?)"$/ do |address, text|
  open_email(address, :with_text => text)
end

#
# Inspect the Email Contents
#

Then /^(?:I|they) should see "([^"]*?)" in the email subject$/ do |text|
  current_email.should have_subject(text)
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see \/([^"]*?)\/ in the email subject$/ do |text|
  current_email.should have_subject(Regexp.new(text))
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see "([^"]*?)" in the email body$/ do |text|
  current_email.default_part_body.to_s.should include(text)
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see \/([^"]*?)\/ in the email body$/ do |text|
  current_email.default_part_body.to_s.should =~ Regexp.new(text)
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see the email delivered from "([^"]*?)"$/ do |text|
  current_email.should be_delivered_from(text)
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see "([^\"]*)" in the email "([^"]*?)" header$/ do |text, name|
  current_email.should have_header(name, text)
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see \/([^\"]*)\/ in the email "([^"]*?)" header$/ do |text, name|
  current_email.should have_header(name, Regexp.new(text))
end

Then /^I should see it is a multi\-part email$/ do
    current_email.should be_multipart
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see "([^"]*?)" in the email html part body$/ do |text|
    current_email.html_part.body.to_s.should include(text)
end

Then /^(?:I|they) should see "([^"]*?)" in the email text part body$/ do |text|
    current_email.text_part.body.to_s.should include(text)
end

#
# Inspect the Email Attachments
#

Then /^(?:I|they) should see (an|no|\d+) attachments? with the email$/ do |amount|
  current_email_attachments.size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end

Then /^there should be (an|no|\d+) attachments? named "([^"]*?)"$/ do |amount, filename|
  current_email_attachments.select { |a| a.filename == filename }.size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end

Then /^attachment (\d+) should be named "([^"]*?)"$/ do |index, filename|
  current_email_attachments[(index.to_i - 1)].filename.should == filename
end

Then /^there should be (an|no|\d+) attachments? of type "([^"]*?)"$/ do |amount, content_type|
  current_email_attachments.select { |a| a.content_type.include?(content_type) }.size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end

Then /^attachment (\d+) should be of type "([^"]*?)"$/ do |index, content_type|
  current_email_attachments[(index.to_i - 1)].content_type.should include(content_type)
end

Then /^all attachments should not be blank$/ do
  current_email_attachments.each do |attachment|
    attachment.read.size.should_not == 0
  end
end

Then /^show me a list of email attachments$/ do
  EmailSpec::EmailViewer::save_and_open_email_attachments_list(current_email)
end

#
# Interact with Email Contents
#

When /^(?:I|they) follow "([^"]*?)" in the email$/ do |link|
  visit_in_email(link)
end

When /^(?:I|they) click the first link in the email$/ do
  click_first_link_in_email
end

#
# Debugging
# These only work with Rails and OSx ATM since EmailViewer uses RAILS_ROOT and OSx's 'open' command.
# Patches accepted. ;)
#

Then /^save and open current email$/ do
  EmailSpec::EmailViewer::save_and_open_email(current_email)
end

Then /^save and open all text emails$/ do
  EmailSpec::EmailViewer::save_and_open_all_text_emails
end

Then /^save and open all html emails$/ do
  EmailSpec::EmailViewer::save_and_open_all_html_emails
end

Then /^save and open all raw emails$/ do
  EmailSpec::EmailViewer::save_and_open_all_raw_emails
end
```

Assuming you can call the various methods in your spec like:

```
open_email(address, :with_text => 'mytext')
current_email.default_part_body.to_s.should include(text)
visit_in_email(link)
EmailSpec::EmailViewer::save_and_open_email(current_email)
```

you can then simulate opening the email address, checking the email contents and visit links in the email or even save the email so you can view it in safari or other browser.

What would capybara give you over and above this?

Comment: Like I said, my goal is to use capybara-webkit to render the HTML email as a image.

Comment: Sorry if it didn't answer your specific question. Perhaps you should rephrase your question to be "How do I make capybara-webkit save an image of my email in test" instead of the more general "Capybara testing emails"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [PutsBox](http://putsbox.com). You can send an email to whatever-you-want@putsbox.com, wait for a few seconds (SMTP stuff ins't instantaneous) then check your email via http://preview.putsbox.com/p/whatever-you-want/last.

```
visit '/'

click_on 'a[href="/users/sign_in"]'
click_on 'a[href="/users/password/new"]'

fill_in '#user_email', with: 'test-reset-password@putsbox.com'

click_on 'input[name="commit"]'

# waits for the email
sleep 60

# opens the email
visit 'http://preview.putsbox.com/p/test-reset-password/last'

# clicks on the reset link
click_on 'body > p:nth-child(3) > a'

# resets the password 
fill_in '#user_password', with: 'password'

fill_in '#user_password_confirmation', with: 'password'

click_on 'input[name="commit"]'
```

Example ^ extracted from this [post tutorial](http://www.pablocantero.com/blog/2015/08/05/test-emails-with-automated-testing-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

I previously did something similar using [Capybara::Node::Simple](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Simple) which allows you to use many Capybara matchers on just a String.

However you mention *"final goal is to use this fork of capybara-webkit to render the HTML email as a image."*

While I'm uncertain why you would do that in your tests, it does mean that you need to load this in a browser. 
 Why not write the string out to a file and `visit` the file with capybara-webkit (or any of the other browsers that can handle `page.save_screenshot`)